# What language could I use to write spells or names of things in my fantasy novel?

Tags: novel, fantasy, language, magic-system

I'm writing a fantasy novel and would like suggestions. I would like to write spells/incantations in a foreign language, preferably a dead language such as Anglo-Saxon. I also would need a translation of the phrase "Crystal dragon". What language can sound either mythical or sort of fantasy-like?

Comment: "What language can sound either mythical or sort of fantasy-like?" Any that your readers don't know. (But for any existing language you can think of, expect there to be a reader who turns out to speak it fluently and embarasses you about all your bad grammar and unintentional double entendres. You might get lucky, but don't count on it.)

Comment: If you want words no one will know but don't want to make your own words up, you could Google 'conlang name generator' and try a few of the options out.

Comment: Clearly you are looking for [Old Enochian](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123149/whats-the-deal-with-the-old-enochian-language).

Answer (score 5):

The best language is one you invent yourself. I know it sounds like a real shortcut to pick a known done language and then just look stuff up in it, but:

- what if that language doesn't have a word for crystal? Or dragon? What if you don't find out until you're 3/4 of the way through the book?
- what if that language has things like endings on adjectives or conjugating verbs, but you didn't learn them properly so you make errors in the book that some readers notice and it bothers them?
- what if you spend more time trying to learn your chosen language than you would have just making one up?

It might not hurt to pick an inspirational language, and then make your words sound like that language -- use the sounds of it, use the rhythm of it. But when things are missing go ahead and make them up. Instead of representing dragon as "snake with wings" because that's all a chosen language can do, you can make up a word, perhaps one that contains fragments of words for wing or fly along with those for snake or lizard, and nobody can tell you it's wrong.

(Most of the spells in Harry Potter are kinda Latin. If you know Latin you'll recognize them without translations, but they're not literally and correctly Latin. That would have been more work.)

Comment: Thanks. I have thought about making up my own language, but I just wouldn't know where to start. I've also experimented with latin, but I don't really want it to sound similar to english.

Comment: probably the best plan is to write it all with those special words in English, but marked out in some way so you can find them. Then when you're done, you will know what words you need. You can start with a real language and tweak it somewhat

Comment: @ElleH. What makes it ‘sound’ similar to English is going to vary significantly by person. Latin (with proper pronunciation) sounds _nothing_ like English to me (largely due to the comparative lack of phonetic diversity in Latin compared to English), but I also studied Latin pretty actively in school so I had a lot of exposure to it. Conversely, to someone from China, Dutch probably sounds a whole lot like English, but no native English speaker is ever likely to think that.

Comment: @ElleH. As far as making up a language, start with figuring out exactly what words you need. If the total required list of words is less than about 30 words long, just come up with random strings of syllables that you like the sound of. If it’s more than 30 words long, you probably want to take the time to figure out a proper grammar first (though it can be a very simple grammar) and then build up a word list from there.

Comment: Making your own language is easier than it sounds. Choose a set of vowels, a set of consonants (you can count things like 'sl' as a consonant, as long as you make sure the word is still pronouncable) and a few basic word structures, like CVC, CVCVCV, etc, and you just fill in randomly. If you need a lot of a specific type of word (like town names) you can come up with morphemes to make it really fancy. Like how lots of cities end in -town or -burg.

Comment: @Devsman *Pretending* that your characters speak a fictional language that you only include a few random phrases of in the text is easy. Actually developing a plausible language with a coherent grammar is extremely hard work.

Comment: @Divizna Yes, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

**Real magic spells are spoken in the mother tongue of the sorcerer**

In the real world, spells were usually in the language of the person speaking them. The effect of the spells was from the rituals that accompanied them or because they addressed certain beings by their names or because language was thought to have power in and of itself (such as in curses).

For example, the "Elfin Knight" in the Child ballad (no. 2) of the same name appears to the narrator-protagonist (presumably a lady) after she speaks that she wishes for him to be with her. That is all. No magic language, no spells or rituals. Just addressing the magic being. (And that, by the way, is why, to this day, some people conventionally avoid saying the names of certain beings.)

Some sources give spells in ancient languages such as Latin or Hebrew. Not because those languages are more magical than, say, English, but because that was the language of the people using the spells. Those that used Ancient Egyptian spells spoke Ancient Egyptian.

**Made up languages aren't magical**

So-called "magical languages" or phrases (such as *Abracadabra*) have usually been invented by stage magicians and fantasy writers and mostly aren't a part of "real" magic (that is, magic that those performing it thought would work).

There are some languages like Enochian that are supposedly those of supernatural beings like angels or demons, but those languages aren't usually necessary to do magic in relation to those beings. John Dee made contact with an Enochian speaking angel using English incantations. The being later taught him Enochian.

**In writing, use the language of your writing for your spells**

Following from how magic is thought to work in the real world, you can simply use the language that you write your novel in for the magic as well. Spells were usually normal sentences and not in any specific form.

**But I really, really want to use another language because it sounds more fantasyish!**

*If the story is set in the real world, use an ancient language from the culture of your story*

If you want to use another language, and your novel is set in the real world (present or past) use Latin or Hebrew or Ancient Egyptian or whatever is a plausible source for the magical knowledge of your sorcerer. Do not use Latin for a story set in ancient China and do not use ancient Chinese for a story set in medieval Scotland. But you can use any language you want for a story set in the present day, because today people from all over the world live anywhere and all the world's knowledge is (potentially) available to anyone. It just has to be plausible within your story that your protagonists learn spells in a language that isn't spoken around them.

*If the story is set in a fantasy world, use an ancient language from the culture your story is based upon*

If your novel is set in a fantasy world, and you want another language, many writers use a language that is related to the culture their fantasy world is based on. If it has Celtic fairies, use a Celtic language. If it has samurai, use Japanese. And so on.

If you use a real language, in a real world or fantasy world setting, make sure your sentences are correct! There will always be a significant number of readers who know that language, and nothing is worse than garbled fake Latin or Gaelic. It will make your writing appear amateurish. Find someone who knows that language to translate your spells for you. There are students of every language imaginable, and many will be willing to help you if all you need is a handful of sentences.

*Or make up a language*

Another option is to make a language up. But since making up languages can be a lot of work (and since many made up languages look and sound laughable), I personally would always simply use English.

*Do not write out the spells at all*

A final option is to not use any specific language at all and just *tell* your readers that a character is saying a spell:

> John said a spell in some language that was unknown to Anna. Then a demon appeared.

Answer (score 1):

A few hundred years back academic works were published in Latin and/or with horribly long sentences to make the information within only available to those who were capable of understanding the structure and language.

Using a different language for magic might be applicable if magic is reserved to only a small part of society or is based on work done by ancient folks. I suggest you start by thinking about where you magic comes from and who can use it. Does a different *magic* language make sense? If so, what would your spells sound like? Maybe kind of brutal like the language of Mordor? Maybe more subtle and gentle like Arwen's whisper when calling for the Bruinen? Maybe like Harry Potter? You could then try to form those words - glue letters together until they sound like in your imagination. Go from there to the next word, start over and so on. At some point you may end up with a pseudo language which contains ten, twenty words, your spells. It’s hard work but making things up in a believable way is just that - hard work.

If that’s too much work and you feel overwhelmed and maybe even stuck you could think about a purely gesture based magic system or something similar to Channeling in Wheel of time. Both solutions are a very neat way to circumvent the need to invent a pseudo magic language. (Not saying that’s why Jordan lets his characters channel instead of using spells)

Comment: "A few hundred years back" Latin was the common language of learning. Saying scholars back then used Latin to keep the common people from understanding magic is like saying scientists today use English to keep the common people from understanding science. Fact is, only 20% of the medieval population could read at all, and everyone who got anything resembling higher education read and spoke Latin fluently.

Comment: The idea that there even can exist "brutal" and "gentle" *languages* is rooted in nationalism and racism, and I'd strongly advise any author who doesn't want to perpetuate some very unfortunate implications to never touch it with a ten-foot pole (except to push it to the junkyard of history where it belongs).

Comment: @Ben: Philosophers from the 19th and 20th century did just that - they used ugly, unnecessarily long sentences to hide their meaning.

Comment: @Divizna: You do know that languages have phonetics, right? German, Russian, Polish - languages with harsh phonetics. French, English, Spanish are phonetically speaking softer languages. All of them are beautiful, yet they are different. Jalapenos vs peppers. How do you make a racism debate out of that?

Comment: @Ben: Apologies, you were referring to the use of Latin. You might be right there.

Comment: @YumYumPizza Assigning descriptions laden with moral value judgment such as "brutal" or "gentle" to languages has nothing to do with phonetics and everything to do with prejudices towards their speakers. Are you seriously claiming that French, English and Spanish are gentle while German, Russian are Polish are brutal, and you don't think it sounds racist? And what a coincidence that is that the "harsh" languages all come from countries with which yours has had clashes in modern history and characters with that background are frequently portrayed as villains in the fiction you consume.

Comment: @Divizna: First of all, in my original post I was talking about a made up language which was designed to emphasize the side the speakers belonged to - evil orcs, good elves. Elrond flinches when Gandalf recites the language of Mordor. It is brutal language in the sense of harsh phonetics, compared to the elven tongue with lots of th-sounds in it. Second, eastern Europe languages have different phonetics than central and western Europe languages - polish and German are different than french and Italian. It is a thing. It has nothing to do with racism, nationalism or clashes in modern history.

Comment: What I like about your answer is the recommendation to think about the function the magic serves within the story: where it comes from, who can use it, how they learn it, and so on, and derive the magic system, including the use of language, from that.

Comment: @Divizna Also, I've never characterized any real language as brutal or gentle. I was talking about designed languages and, in my first comment, about differences in phonetics. Soft edges (in phonetics and art) are generally perceived as friendlier whilst hard edges are perceived and as rough and bold. Look at the Klingon language - a warrior's language with lots of Ks in it.

Answer (score -1):

Technically the magic language you want is the one spoken by the things that provide the magic. The gods (or demons or fairies) won't respond to "hello me old mucker, can I have a fireball now please" if they don't speak English. But if you said the same thing in Fairie or Demonic, then they might.

So what language to use, whichever one sounds unusual enough. Try one of the lesser-spoken languages like Welsh or Finnish and butcher it enough that someone who speaks those languages will recognise it only as gibberish, or make up your own. Google Translate has a heap of unusual language translations whoch in turn can provide a resource to easily make "hello me old mucker, can I have a fireball now please" into the far more mystical and magical sounding "kumusta ako daan nga higala, mahimo ba ko nga usa ka bola sa kalayo karon palihug"

and Crystal Dragon, how about "shato yekristaro".

Comment: "Demons, as pure spirits, do not need a language to communicate with each other; they simply communicate at will through the power of thought. Human beings communicate through words, which are symbolic representations of our thoughts. Spiritual beings, on the other hand, transmit thought in a pure state without the need for mediation or signs." ~ [Fr. José Antonio Fortea](https://spiritualdirection.com/2014/02/13/language-demons-speak)

Comment: @Ben My demons are not the same as yours. I wonder what the questioner's are like?!